# How can I remove extra characters from a column?

Tags: postgresql, csv, openoffice.org

I have a table with Customer/Phone/City/State/Zip/etc.. 
Occasionally, I'll be importing the info from a .csv file, and sometimes the zipcode is formatted like this: xxxxx-xxxx and I only need it to be a general, 5 digit zip code.

How can I delete the last 5 characters without having to do it from Excel, cell by cell (which is what I'm doing now)?

Thanks

EDIT: This is what I used after Craig's suggestion and it worked. However, some of the zip entries are canadian zipcodes and often time they are formated x1x-x2x. Running this deletes the last character in the field.

How could I remedy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do one of these 3 ideas:

- use an ETL tool to filter the data during insert;
- `COPY` into a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table then do an `INSERT INTO real_table SELECT ...` that transforms the data with a suitable `substring(...)` call; or
- Write a simple Perl/Python/whatever script that reads the csv, transforms it as desired, and inserts the results into PostgreSQL. I'd use Python with the `csv` module and psycopg2's `copy_from`.

Such an `insert into ... select` might look like:

```
INSERT INTO real_table(col1, col2, zip)
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  substring(zip from 1 for 5)
FROM temp_table;
```

Comment: Craig's list is great. I like option 2 best. (I actually like option 1 best in many cases but with the giant caveat that many ETL tools are expensive and all have a steep learning curve.)

Comment: @mdahlman look into Talend Studio, CloverETL, Pentaho Kettle.

Comment: I just mean learning Talend is a mighty steep learning curve compared to `substr(zip,1,5)` if that fully solves the requirement. But the tools certainly offer a lot of additional power.

Comment: @mdahlman Oh, totally agree. That's why I usually just use a python script.

Comment: Could you give me an example on option 2? I already use a temporary table into which I copy data from the .csv file and then insert into the real one.

Comment: @Azar_Javed, please post the code you use now to insert into your real table.